# Using $q.when to resolve a promise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some questions regarding using $q.when.  Here's the code that I have:

Here's the code that I have:

```
resolve: {
   get: ['$q','testService','$stateParams',
         ($q,tes,$stateParams) => {
             // I am doing a check here to see if the qs
             // array has been populated. If it has then
             // I want to return a resolve. If not then 
             // I want to return getQuestions() 
             $q.when($stateParams.qs);

             // getQuestions() will return a promise

          }]
        },
```

Can someone give me some advice on how I can do this? Here's one idea that I have but I am not sure if this is the way it should be done. In particular I am not sure if I need to include `return` and also not sure if I need a second $when in the resolve part of the first $when.

```
resolve: {
   get: ['$q','testService','$stateParams',
         ($q,tes,$stateParams) => { 
             return $q.when($stateParams.qs)
             .then(() => {
                 return $q.when("success");
             }, 
             () => {
                 return getQuestions();
             }   
          }]
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
resolve: {
   get: ['$q','testService','$stateParams',
         ($q,tes,$stateParams) => { 
             if ($stateParams.qs) {
                return $q.when();
             else {
                return getQuestions();
             }
 },
```

Answer (score 3):

`$q.when(someVariable)` is used to wrap your data in an already resolved promise and pass it along the promise chain when returning it

when resolving like so

```
resolve: {
    get: function(response) {
        return $q.when(response.data);
    }
}
```

you need to return the promise otherwise you will break the chain and the code below wouldn't run properly.

you basically pass a resolved promise object into your controller, so inside you controller you could chain it into another `then`

inside controller:

```
get.then(function(data) {
    console.debug("this is my raw data: ", data);
}, function(rejected) {
    // this won't run
}
```

the [$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) cover this function

**EDIT 1**

so your resolve code should be something like this

```
    resolve: {
        get: ['$q','testService','$stateParams', ($q,tes,$stateParams) => { 
             return $q.when($stateParams.qs);  
      }]
    },
```

and inside the controller

```
get.then(() => {
             return "success";
         }, 
         () => {
             return getQuestions();
         })
```

but because you already return $q.when (which is always resolved), the line `return getQuestions();` would never run. so you should probably remove the $q.when inside the resolve.

**EDIT 2**

if you wish the `getQuestion` to resolve after qs is then do it like so

```
resolve: {
    get: function(response) {
        return $q.when("success"); // or just return "success"
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response==="success") { // you can skip it
            return $q.when(getQuestions());
        } else {
            return $q.reject("Some error"); // a throw would work the same
        }
    })
}
```

if you don't mind the order use $q.all

```
get: function() {
    return $q.all(["success", getQuestions()]).then(function(results) {
        var res1 = results[0]; // success
        var res2 = results[1]; // the questions
)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am still pretty confused. Can you show me an example of how you think I could implement the returning of a promise with the code in the question so I could get a better understanding.

Comment: In particular I am trying to use: when(value, [successCallback], [errorCallback], [progressCallback]); to either make a call to getQuestions or not depending if I already have the data. In this example I don't actually have a controller as it is ui-router resolve method.

Comment: either way. if you want to chain another '.then' method to your promise and you want it to both have handlers for reject and resolve, you should never return only using a `when`, as it will only activate the resolve handler in the next chain. if you want to  access the reject handler you should either use reject or throw

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't have a controller I have a service :-)  But if you don't mind can you show how getQuestions could be added to be inside the resolve. I want to be sure the resolve has not returned true until either the qs was found or getQuestions has completed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: when you resolve the qs, chain another `then` and inside that one return the `getQuestions `.
or you can use $q.all, it will accept an array of promises and would run a `then` after all promises are resolved

Comment: Can you add that into your answer with some code so I can accept ;-) Thanks

Comment: Hi, I saw your update but where does it check to see if $stateParams. qs is null or not? Could you add your code into the code of the question so it could be a bit more clear as I am still not sure because you don't check to see if qs is populated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Please please add "resolve: {
   get: ['$q','testService','$stateParams',
         ($q,tes,$stateParams) => {
to your questions and show me how I can check $stateParams.qs to see if it is null ( i need to getQuestions() ) or not null ( I just need to return a resolve) Thanks